# How to say 'I just wanted to check...' formally?

Tags: word-choice

How to say the following in a formal way?

> I just wanted to check...

Is it kind of like this:

> 参考までに伺いたいんですが、新しい求人が出ましたか？

Comment: I think this is a smart way to say it, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is almost perfect.

The better one is:

> 参考までに伺いたい**の**ですが、新しい求人**は**出ましたか？

First, in the phrase in question, using ん instead of の is not formal. Use の here.

Additionally, in the latter part of the sentence, using は instead of が sounds natural.